# Ruby FizzBuzz using arrays, my logic seems right but it is getting an error

Tags: ruby, fizzbuzz

FizzBuzz, a classic problem, returns all the numbers up to N with a slight twist. If a number is divisible by 3, it is replaced with "fizz". If it's divisible by 5, it's replaced with "buzz". If it's divisible by both, it's replaced with "fizzbuzz"

I keep getting this Error message:

```
comparison of Fixnum with nil failed
```

Can someone explain this error message to me please? Also why is the code not working?

```
def fizz_buzz(n)
  arr = (1..n).to_a 
  i = 0

  while arr[i] < arr[n]
    if i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0 
      arr[i] = 'fizzbuzz'
    elsif i % 3 == 0 
      arr[i] = 'fizz'
    elsif i % 5 == 0 
      arr[i] = 'buzz'
    else 
      arr[i] = i
      i += 1 
    end
  end

  return arr 
end

fizz_buzz(12)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your conditions are just a bit off, give this a try:

```
def fizz_buzz(n)
  arr = (1..n).to_a 
  i = 0

  while i < n
    if arr[i] % 3 == 0 && arr[i] % 5 == 0 
      arr[i] = 'fizzbuzz'
    elsif arr[i] % 3 == 0 
      arr[i] = 'fizz'
    elsif arr[i] % 5 == 0 
      arr[i] = 'buzz'
    end

    i+=1
  end

  return arr 
end
```

Trying to access arr[n] puts you outside the bounds of the array which returns `nil` in Ruby.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 0):

@brad-melanson beat me to the straight-forward answer to your question, so I'll share an answer which uses some common Ruby idioms (passing a range to the `Array` constructor and `map`), which simplify things, prevent you from having to do any iteration bookkeeping and prevent the possibility of off-by-one errors, out-of-bounds errors, etc.

```
def fizz_buzz(n)
  Array(1..12).map do |n|
    if n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0 
      'fizzbuzz'
    elsif n % 3 == 0 
      'fizz'
    elsif n % 5 == 0 
      'buzz'
    else
      n
    end
  end
end

result = fizz_buzz 12 
# result => [1, 2, "fizz", 4, "buzz", "fizz", 7, 8, "fizz", "buzz", 11, "fizz"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the code the ruby way, by using blocks and guards, I don't remember last time I used a while loop in ruby :)

Also, [Array.new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new) accepts a block as an argument which you can exploit to build your Array in a single step:

```
def fizz_buzz(n)
  Array.new(n) do |index|
    x = index + 1
    case 
      when x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0 then "fizzbuzz"
      when x % 3 == 0 then "fizz"
      when x % 5 == 0 then "buzz"
      else x
    end
  end
end
```

Notice I used 1 as a base index and not 0, you can just remove **x = index + 1** and replace **x** with **index** to have it working in a zero index base

A solution with a block instead of the while loop, and guards

```
def fizz_buzz(n)
  arr = (1..n).to_a 

  0.upto(n - 1) do |i|
    arr[i] = "fizzbuzz" and next if i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0
    arr[i] = "fizz" and next if i % 3 == 0
    arr[i] = "buzz" if i % 5 == 0
  end

  arr
end
```

Comment: Your second solution doesn't quite work. For example  `fizz_buzz(4) #=> ["fizzbuzz", 2, 3, "fizz"]`